Caused by: : Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 34
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
applicationId "com.english4.youKurdish"
minSdk 21
targetSdkVersion 34
versionCode 10
versionName "1.9"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
namespace 'com.english4.youKurdish.D1'
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:34.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:chromecast-sender:0.23'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:34.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
def lottieVersion = "3.4.0"
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'

//glide library
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'


implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.2"
implementation"com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0"

}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 34
defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true
applicationId "com.english4.youKurdish"
minSdk 21
targetSdkVersion 34
versionCode 10
versionName "1.9"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
namespace 'com.english4.youKurdish.D1'
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:34.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:chromecast-sender:0.23'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:34.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
def lottieVersion = "3.4.0"
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$lottieVersion"

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'

//glide library
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'


implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.2"
implementation"com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0"

}
